Do we always have to run npx husky init after installing husky to get the hooks to work?
I've created a base/starter project with files commonly used for Github open source projects that is intended for extension by other projects.  It also comes with commitlint and husky for linting commits.
So if someone clones it and runs the following the commits get linted.
git clone git@github.com:fireflysemantics/fs-github-flow-docs-starter.git
cd fs-github-flow-docs-starter/
npm i && npx husky init
echo "" > .husky/pre-commit
git add . && git commit -m "linting error"
⧗   input: linting error
✖   subject may not be empty [subject-empty]
✖   type may not be empty [type-empty]

✖   found 2 problems, 0 warnings
ⓘ   Get help: https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/#what-is-commitlint

husky - commit-msg script failed (code 1)

I was wondering if there is a way to get it to work without have to rerun npx husky init?  So that users could just do:
git clone git@github.com:fireflysemantics/fs-github-flow-docs-starter.git
cd fs-github-flow-docs-starter/
npm i
git add . && git commit -m "linting error"
⧗   input: linting error
✖   subject may not be empty [subject-empty]
✖   type may not be empty [type-empty]

✖   found 2 problems, 0 warnings
ⓘ   Get help: https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/#what-is-commitlint

husky - commit-msg script failed (code 1)

Thoughts?

Git intentionally does not allow you to automatically run code when someone checks out a repository. Doing so would pose an enormous security risk (what if insteady of husky, someone instead decided to run rm -rf /?). The only thing you can do is document the necessary setup process and perhaps provide a script your developers can run manually to enable the pre-commit checks.

@larsks true indeed.  I was hoping there was perhaps some way of building what npx husky init does into the repository so that it's already done when people clone it.  At first I thought it just created the .husky folder ...

OK - When we run npx husky init husky adds a prepare script to package.json.
So I updated package.json with the script and now the script block looks like this and commit linting works as expected.
  "scripts": {
    "release": "npx release-it",
    "prepare": "husky"
  },

